# NameError: name 'per' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я решил сделать небольшой квест, но столкнулся с этой ошибкой NameError: name 'per' is not defined эта ошибка появляется и NameError: name 'vid' is not defined также вот так NameError: name 'vih' is not defined.  Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
    import random
    print("")

    vid = int(input())
    if vid == 1:
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")

    if vid == 2:
        print("")
        raise SystemExit
    guess = random.randint(1,6)
    print("")
    print(guess)

    if guess == 1:
        print("")
        print("")
        vih = input()
    if guess == 2:
        print("")
        print("")
    if guess == 3:
        print("")
    if guess == 4:
        print("")
        print("")
        per = input()
    if guess == 5:
        print("")
        print("")
    if guess == 6:
        print("")
        print("")

    if vih == "":
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
    if vih == "":
        print(" ")

    if per == "":
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
    if per == "":
        print("")
        print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том что когда вы проверяете vih, то не факт что выполнилось vih = input() 
Попробуйте сделать так. Вроде работает.

```
import random
print("")

vid = int(input())
if vid == 1:
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")

if vid == 2:
    print("")
    raise SystemExit
guess = random.randint(1,6)
print("")
print(guess)

if guess == 1:
    print("")
    print("")
    vih = input()
    if vih == "":
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
    if vih == "":
        print(" ")

if guess == 2:
    print("")
    print("")
if guess == 3:
    print("")
if guess == 4:
    print("")
    print("")
    per = input()
    if per == "":
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
    if per == "":
        print("")
        print("")
if guess == 5:
    print("")
    print("")
if guess == 6:
    print("")
    print("")
```